# PYQT4- pyodbc driver error

Tags: python, sql, runtime, pyqt4, pyodbc

i keep getting this pyodbc driver error and i can not fix it at all can anyone help? i am using pyqt4 with microsoft access to act as a data repository. Ignore any dodgy indentations.

here is my error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "F:\computing\Payroll v2 2\mainwindow.py", line 53, in loadUpcomingBirthdaysForm
self.ui.upcomingBirthdaysForm = UpcomingBirthdays.UpcomingBirthdays()
File "F:\computing\Payroll v2 2\UpcomingBirthdays.py", line 22, in __init__
cursor.execute("select Forename,Surname,DOB from employees where (DOB=?))",9)
pyodbc.Error: ('HYC00', '[HYC00] [Microsoft][ODBC Microsoft Access Driver]Optional feature not implemented  (106) (SQLBindParameter)')
```

here is my code:

```
from PyQt4 import uic
from PyQt4 import QtCore,QtGui
import validation
import pyodbc
import datetime

( Ui_UpcomingBirthdays, QMainWindow ) = uic.loadUiType( 'UpcomingBirthdays.ui' )

class UpcomingBirthdays ( QMainWindow ):
"""Upcoming Birthdays inherits QMainWindow"""

def __init__ ( self, parent = None ):
    QMainWindow.__init__( self, parent )
    self.ui = Ui_UpcomingBirthdays()
    self.ui.setupUi( self )
    today = datetime.date.today()
    thismonth= int(today.strftime("%m")[0:2])
    thisday= int(today.strftime("%d")[0:2])
    cnxn = pyodbc.connect('Driver={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)}; Dbq=F:\\computing\\Payroll v2 2\\employees.accdb')
    cursor = cnxn.cursor()
    cursor.execute("select Forename,Surname,DOB from employees where (DOBmonth=?))",thismonth)
    residentList = cursor.fetchall()
    cnxn.close()
    self.ui.residentTableWidget.setRowCount(0)
    for item in residentList:
        print (item)
        rowcount = self.ui.residentTableWidget.rowCount()
        self.ui.residentTableWidget.insertRow(rowcount)
        self.ui.residentTableWidget.setItem(rowcount,0,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[0])))
        self.ui.residentTableWidget.setItem(rowcount,1,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[1])))
        self.ui.residentTableWidget.setItem(rowcount,2,QtGui.QTableWidgetItem(str(item[2])))







def __del__ ( self ):
    self.ui = None
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I figured it out, the fault lies in the following line:

```
cursor.execute("select Forename,Surname,DOB from employees where (DOBmonth=?))",thismonth)
```

i should have changed the "thismonth" variable into a string e.g.

```
str(thismonth))
```

Comment: Looks like there's an extra parenthesis in that line also. Don't forget you can accept your own answers.